# How to get same id different values in javascript json array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How to get same id different values in javascript json array object and push it in array.

This is actual json data,

```
var data = [{
        "areaid": 25,
        "wardid": 5
    },
    {
        "areaid": 24,
        "wardid": 5
    },
    {
        "areaid": 23,
        "wardid": 5
    },
    {
        "areaid": 22,
        "wardid": 5
    },
    {
        "areaid": 21,
        "wardid": 4
    },
    {
        "areaid": 20,
        "wardid": 4
    },
    {
        "areaid": 19,
        "wardid": 4
    },
    {
        "areaid": 18,
        "wardid": 3
    },
    {
        "areaid": 17,
        "wardid": 3
    },
    {
        "areaid": 16,
        "wardid": 3
    }];
```

And the output i want,
for wardid: 3

```
    [{
        "areaid": 18
    },{
        "areaid": 17
    },{
        "areaid": 16
    }]
```

for wardid: 4

```
    [{
        "areaid": 21
    },{
        "areaid": 20
    },{
        "areaid": 19
    }]
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, but we are more than happy to help you get your solution working.

Comment: filter + map is an easy way to do this

Comment: For those taking the time to answer might I suggest that you explain your answers in order that the OP, and future visitors, might learn something useful? Although as the question currently stands it doesn't seem worth answering on the grounds that the OP has demonstrated no effort at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **`data[i].wardid`** to retrieve the Ward ID from inside a simple `for loop` and compare that same ID with any value that which in turns, retrieve the Area ID value of that same object.

In the following code snippet, I appended the corresponding Area IDs of the searched Ward ID to a new array as well as to a div to illustrate the code better. Check the **Code Snippet** or this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/t487yhbo/36/) to see how the following code works:

```js
/* JavaScript */
var val = document.getElementById("val");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var outPutArray = [];

function checkId(){
  outPutArray = [];
  output.innerHTML = `<p>The following wards have that ID:</p>`;
  if(!val.value) {
    alert('Please input ID');
  } else {
   
    for(i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if(data[i].wardid == val.value) {
        var x = {};
        x.warid = data[i].wardid;
        x.areaid = data[i].areaid;   
        outPutArray.push(x);
       output.innerHTML += `<div>Area ${data[i].areaid}</div>`;
      }
    }
    console.log(outPutArray);
  }  
}

btn.addEventListener("click", checkId);

var data = [{"areaid":25,"wardid":5},{"areaid":24,"wardid":5},{"areaid":23,"wardid":5},{"areaid":22,"wardid":5},{"areaid":21,"wardid":4},{"areaid":20,"wardid":4},{"areaid":19,"wardid":4},{"areaid":18,"wardid":3},{"areaid":17,"wardid":3},{"areaid":16,"wardid":3}];
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="number" id="val" min="3" max="5" name="wardId" />
<button id="btn">
Check Id
</button>
<div id="output">
<p>
The following Areas have that Ward ID:
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AndrewL.

Comment: @kranthikumarTelu I have edited the solution a bit more to return a new array with the objects matching the ID as well as render the divs too. The new array is logged into the console so you can check it out.